# Integration of activemerchant offsite payment Directebanking in Spree

Tags: spree, activemerchant

I am about to integrate that activemerchant offsite payment method into spree: https://github.com/Shopify/offsite_payments/blob/master/lib/offsite_payments/integrations/directebanking.rb

I have created a `Spree::Gateway` class in `app/models/gateway`, so that I can configure the method in my admin panel:

```
class Spree::Gateway::Directebanking < Spree::Gateway
    preference :credential1, :string
    preference :credential2, :string
    preference :credential3, :string
    preference :credential4, :string

    def provider_class
        ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Directebanking
    end
end
```

Also I have added these lines to config/application.rb:

```
config.after_initialize do  
    Rails.configuration.spree.payment_methods << Spree::Gateway::SofortUeberweisung
end
```

However, now I am stuck with three things:

1. I am not sure if I have added the correct preferences in the Spree::Gateway class. How do I find out which preferences I need to add for the directebanking module?
2. What is the payment workflow? I get 'undefined method new' for ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Directebanking:Module' error if I try to check out with the payment method.
3. How can I disable the default Javascript behaviour of showing credit card fields, such as name, credit card number, cvc, etc? I want the application to redirect to the Directebanking.service_url with click on 'Checkout'.

Comment: did you find the solution? I have the same question for different payment gateway

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question, but here you go.

offsite_payment gem was only recently extracted from ActiveMerchant. It is better for you to use ActiveMerchant only for now.

If you want to use offsite_payment, I think you should use the newly renamed classes:

```
def provider_class
    OffsitePayments::Integrations::Directebanking
end
```